# wget won't ignore no-follow attributes

Tags: linux, wget

I'm using the following command to download all files off of a webpage:

```
wget --recursive "http://example.com"
```

This gives me sometimes the following error:

```
no-follow attribute found in www.example.com. Will not follow any links on this page
```

According to [gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/faq.html), I have to add `-e robots=off --wait 0.25` to my command.

My final command looks like this (I don't want `span-hosts`):

```
wget --recursive -e robots=off --wait 0.5 "http://example.com"
```

However I am still getting the above error. What can I do to ignore those attributes?

Answer (score 4):

The right way is there. You just have to try it

`wget -r -erobots=off "your_url"`

Answer (score 0):

The message is a bug, wget is in fact following the links despite showing the message "Will not follow any links on this page".

This has been [fixed on the master](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git/commit/?id=f1cccd2c454fb416e75a22b358b0a11266642007) branch and should be fixed in the next version of wget.

See [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/mprq89/wget_respects_nofollow_attribute_despite_e/guct2s5/) for more details.

Answer (score -2):

In my case I had a syntax error in `--follow-tags`. Removing the syntax error let wget continue despite the no-follow attribute.

See more info here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/258850

Comment: The OP isn't using `--follow-tags`, though